# How to insert result of a stored procedure and a varchar into a temp table?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, insert

I would like to insert into a temp table the result from a stored procedure in one column and a char in another column. I have something like this:

```
set @myvar = testvar
insert into @temp ( ID)
exec mysp
```

How can I add `@myvar` to `@temp` where `@temp` has two columns : `ID` and `Var` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the sp is maintained by you, you could pass the variable to the sp and get it returned with the other values.

If it is not mainained by you then you could define two tables , one to store the results from the sp and one to join them with your variable.

```
DECLARE @temp1 AS Table
(
    // Columns returned by the sp
)
DECLARE @temp2 AS Table
(
    MyVar VARCHAR(100),
    // Columns returned by the sp
)
DECLARE @myvar VARCHAR(100)
SET @myvar = 'testvar'

insert into @temp1
exec mysp

INSERT INTO @Temp2
SELECT @myvar,* 
FROM   @Temp1
```